# Searchbar controller with UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I am using a searchbar controller with `UITableview`.The search results are coming properly.I have set the row `height`,`separator` `style` to none and `backgroundColor` `clearColor` and `tranparent`.But the issue is the result table view does not have all these styles.what to do?How to apply table view styles for search result tableview?

Comment: show me some of the code first.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

i hope this is the way, you are accessing the tableView. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: in the viewDidLoad of the UIViewController where you have the searchBar added.

Comment: But now the first table is coming and search result table is coming over the first table.

Comment: its because u are using clearColor. u mentioned it in the question, so i told you how to use it. What all features you need to add exactly?

Comment: you must be having 2 tables. and can you please post some code so that i can help u out.

Answer (score 0):

The searchbar controller doesn't have any direct dependency other than providing the input to the tableview(datasource)

I think (may be) Memory changed for the tableview(memory : allocated it again)